# App Crash when a push notification is received and application closed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash, android-notifications

My Xamarin Android app crashes when a push notification is received..!

Here is the error :

> System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xbee2dcd8 (key_handle 0x1302a92b) of Java type 'md53ff9574f15073ce2830b1527af878807/GcmListener' as managed type 'DriversInfo.Droid.GcmListener'. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Here is the code to receive the notification (GCMListener):

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"notification data : {data}");

        //Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "OnMessageReceived");
        var message = data.GetString("message");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyGcmListenerService - From:    " + from);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyGcmListenerService - Message: " + message);

        var isSilent = data.GetBoolean("isSilent");

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await this.Engine.ResumeAsync());

        if (!isSilent)
        {
            NotificationHelper.DisplayNotification(this, "Drivers Info", message);
        }
    }
```

And the code to show the notification :

```
        public static bool DisplayNotification(Context context, string title, string desc,
                                           NotificationId notificationId = 0)
    {
        // Set up an intent so that tapping the notifications returns to this app:
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        // Create a PendingIntent; we're only using one PendingIntent (ID = 0):
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(desc)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Logo);

        //if (Settings.AppAcceptsSoundNotifications)
        builder.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification));

        // Build the notification:
        var notification = builder.Build();

        // Get the notification manager:
        var notificationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        notificationManager?.Notify((int) notificationId, notification);
        return true;
    }
```

I did not write this code and I would like to learn more about it !
I'm a bit disappointed and new Xamarin/Android developper, and need community help/explanations.

Thanks ;)

**EDIT**

Here is more details about the app crash (no context) :

> AndroidRuntime Parameter name: context at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService (Autofac.IComponentContext context, Autofac.Core.Service service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00003] in <ca1ca41f44e0487e9a15b2f64e38c7de>:0 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve (Autofac.IComponentContext context, System.Type serviceType, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00007] in :0 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService] (Autofac.IComponentContext context, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService] (Autofac.IComponentContext context) [0x00000] in :0 at DriversInfo.Droid.GcmListener..ctor () [0x0000c] in <41c8506acadd4ded8f0bf3c09ac45dbb>:0 at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.6e5c2775-7f90-4dd7-a6af-e9481e583260(intptr,object[]) at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x000df] in <52508bfa6a8a441688f64accb5488049>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x00168] in <52508bfa6a8a441688f64accb5488049>:0 at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.ae816e3f-b83f-4390-af32-80f1fa8830a2(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) at mono.android.TypeManager.n_activate(Native Method) at mono.android.TypeManager.Activate(TypeManager.java:7) at md5c4b050970b34fabb7ecdb34ca8ce9387.GcmListener.(GcmListener.java:23) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3657) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:219) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` You need to debug it to determine what is `null`, is it `from`, `data`, etc...

Comment: I can't debug that, because the app is closed at this time ! Have you an idea about how to do that ?

Comment: Did you solve it?